# How to suppress Java Authentication Popup

Tags: java, windows

[image]

We keep seeing the below java popup in an environment(Windows Server 2008 r2 Citrix) . We don't however see this on Windows 7 desktop. Both environments have the same java version and setup.

Any idea why this appears and when it appears it keeps popping up.

Comment: Are you running the application under the same (domain?) user on both systems?

Comment: I dont think this really has anything to do with jave itself. I suspect the login scripts on the desktop are setup for people to use the browser as a normal thing whereas the server is not. The proxy authentication is obviously not setup normally possibly because it is considered a security issue.

Comment: @Thomas same domain and users